# Can't get python server data from android client

Tags: android, python, sockets

I want to write a simple android app that sends text to python server and then puts its answer (in our case: how many vowels in the data) and use Logcat to see it really got the data.
Everything works just fine excepts for the part where the clients waits for the server response.
It just getting stuck there even though the server says it sent the data back to the client.

Does anyone have an idea what might have caused this problem?

UPDATE:

After sniffing with Wireshark I saw that the data the client and server sends to each other is "Malformed packet". Anyone knows why?

my client code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.1";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
        Log.i("Tag","sent " + str);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
        try {

            String read = input.readLine();
            Log.i("Tag","got " + read);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

my server code:

```
import socket
   srv_sock = socket.socket()
   ip = "0.0.0.0" # means  local
   port = 3001  # 0 means get random free port
   srv_sock.bind((ip, port))
   srv_sock.listen(5)
   while True:
       (new_sock, address) = srv_sock.accept()
       print "Hello! this is a vowels server! You need to send a word or a 
   sentence and I'll give you the number of vowels in it!"
        while True:
            data = new_sock.recv(1024)
            if data == "" :
               print "Client Disconnected"
               break
            print "Received<<< " + data
            data = data.upper()
            to_send = "Num of vowels is "
            cnt=0
            if data.isdigit():
               to_send = "ERROR:Number doesn't have any vowels!"
            else:
                for letter in data:
                   if (letter == 'A' or letter == 'E' or letter == 'O' or letter 
    == 'U' or letter == 'I'):
                        cnt += 1
                to_send += str(cnt)
            new_sock.send(unicode(to_send + "\n"))
            print "Sent   >>>" + to_send
        new_sock.close()
   srv_sock.close()
```

Comment: If it's pretty clear, then enlighten me...

Comment: If you want something in return except for thanks, then I don't need your help...

Comment: ah lol... it is just a figure of speech. So can you help me?

Comment: `txt.setText(data);`. Your app should crash on that statement. And in the logcat you should find the stacktrace and exceptions. You cannot do that gui action in the run() of a runnable. Take it out or use `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: thanks but that's not my problem. the problem is the app doesn't even enter the while part, that means it doesn't get answer from the server

Comment: No. That probably means that there is no connection to begin with. Do you see this log statement? `Log.i(Tag,"connected");`.

Comment: Yes. I get all the logs except for this one 'Log.i(Tag, "got data: " + data);'. Also I see in the server side that it got what the client sent him and it sends a response

Comment: Please tell exactly what the server sends as response. That code is much to cryptic.

Comment: You use writeUTF() and readUTF() in your client. Where in your python code can we see that python expects such utf strings and also sends them? I hope you realize that such utf strings are different from normal strings.

Comment: The server sends the sentence: "Num of vowels is" + num of vowels in the data

Comment: `new_sock.send(to_send.encode("UTF-8"))` makes the data unicode

Comment: which method should I use to get string data as ascii not unicode?

Comment: writeUTF() first sends some bytes indicating the length of the following string. readUTF() first reads some bytes so it knows the length of following string. I was not talking about unicode or ascii.

Comment: I didn't know it... Doesn't UTF means unicode? Is there any other way to send and recieve strings?

Comment: Yes there is. But what i do not understand is that if i tell you that the client sends some size indicating bytes for every string the receiver should receive them first too. Now did you see them at server side?

Comment: You can just use out.write().

Comment: After a long time, I decided to start all over again. I updated the client code. The server gets the data and sends back a response which I cannot get. It stucks on the `input.readline()`. In wireshark it says "Malformed packet". Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: If a client tries to read a line then the server should have send one. Now did the server?

Comment: Yes, the server sent a response (it prints te sent data as an evidence), but again in Wireshark it says the packet is 'malformed packet'.

Comment: The server should send a line as response. Now does the server send a line?

Comment: I think so. It prints the line after it sends it

Comment: It looks as if you do not understand what i mean by sending a line. A line is not just some characters. And the receiving side is trying to read a line. Not just some characters. Again: if the server does nkt send a line then the clientcannot read a line. Please explain what a line is.

Comment: You are right - I thought a line is just a string. Can you please explain what it really is?

Comment: A line is a string that ends with a new line character. Like in a text editer. If you press the enter key you start on a new line. `String "this is a line\n";` So if the receiving side is trying to read a line with readLine() then it waits until the new line character `\n` is found. Which you did not sent until now.

Comment: changed it to send `unicode(to_send +"\n")` but it still doesn't work. also tried to send ascii

Comment: Your code can never work. The server will receive nothing from your client. And your client will crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Can you please explain me why it receives nothing and how to solve it?

Comment: `The server will receive nothing from your client.` You did not confirm or deny that.

Comment: `And your client will crash with a NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You did not confirm or deny that. You did not even comment. Difficult helping in this way.

Comment: Already told you that the server gets the data from the client and even sends it back. About the exception, it doesn't crash. What do you think is the problem with my code?

Comment: The network code in onClick() should give a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which would let your app crash. Please explain why you would not get one. Are there things you did not tell us but should?

Comment: Wow, I forgot to check if I get an exception,now I do all the communication part in the ClientThread runnable and it finally worked. Thank you for your help!